# ASP.NET Crystal Report - display 25 columns

Tags: crystal-reports

I have 25 columns im my table and i have to show all columns in Asp.net Crystal report
But the header  and details fields in crystal is not sufficient.......

how can i....Awaiting for ur valuable Response

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the Report to *Landscape*.

- [Crystal Reports in ASP.NET ->
  Landscape](http://www.vbforums.com/archive/index.php/t-370405.html)
- [ASP Net - crystal report viewer in
  landscape](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t119387-crystal-report-viewer-in-landscape.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can arrange the Printer PAGE size like A4, A3, A2 etc apart from landscape.
Also can arrange the fields in vertical manner pagewise if possible.